# How to deploy flask web application in Godaddy

Tags: python-3.x, database, flask, broken-links

I am very new to flask and GoDaddy, from past fews days I am trying to deploy a Flask and mysql base web application in Godaddy , just wanted to know how i can deploy this in godaddy?

I tried many documentation on the internet to deploy this but they didn't helped me alot.

Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.